# ipad NSArray of ViewControllers

Tags: ipad, view, controller, nsarray

is it possible to declare an NSArray withobjects of view controllers? 
I'm trying to use two  buttons to call an array that will loop through and count through 20 different views.
Right now, my array works in calling and displaying multiple images in a single view application. 
what would i do to create an nsarray of view controllers, so that every time the "next" action method is called, a new view is loaded, and essentially, counted through the array?

This is currently what I have listed in my array

-(IBAction)getNextView {

```
imageArray=[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[firstViewController.view],
[secondViewController.view],
[thirdViewController.view];
```

}

But I think i am missing a valid point of updating the mainview with the elements in the array...

Thanks!

UPDATE :
This is what I am trying to achieve...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes why not, you can create an NSArray with objects of viewControllers

Comment: also if you have a look at UITabBarController class reference then you will find a property viewController which returns a NSArray of view controllers.